# Android: Debug vs. Release (SDK) performance

Tags: android

I've noticed that launching some of the activities in the Android Emulator while running Debug takes about 11 seconds to show, but when I compile it for release, activities take only about 2 seconds to show. I have no breakpoints set. I only have several textviews/editviews/a mapview in these layouts running 2.1 (API Level 7). Is this normal?

Comment: Yes.............

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, debug mode handles exceptions a little differently than release mode.  It allows you to see in more detail of what is going on.  But it also makes your program run slower..

Answer (score 3):

and also, debug mode stores values of all the variables in all the steps. so this time difference will increase with increase in no of variables.